# find_min_box_constrained just quits at boundary?

Tags: c++, mathematical-optimization, dlib

I call `find_min_box_constrained` like this:

```
matrix<double,nparam,1> lb ={0,0,0,0};
matrix<double,nparam,1> ub = {2,2,2,2};

find_min_box_constrained(lbfgs_search_strategy(100),  
        objective_delta_stop_strategy(1e-15).be_verbose(),
        targetf, derivative(targetf), params,lb,ub );
```

which yields the following output:

> iteration: 0   objective: 3786.68
>
> iteration: 1   objective: 294.485
>
> iteration: 2   objective: 294.485
>
> iteration: 3   objective: 294.484
>
> iteration: 4   objective: 294.481
>
> iteration: 5   objective: 294.452
>
> iteration: 6   objective: 294.157
>
> iteration: 7   objective: 291.148
>
> iteration: 8   objective: 252.786
>
> iteration: 9   objective: 375.851
>
> iteration: 10   objective: 375.851

And my `params` vector eventually is exactly {2,2,2,2} (the upper bound), where `targetf(ub) = 375.851`.

Why does `find_min_box_constrainted` return that value, even though it apparently already encountered something better (252 at iteration 8)?

Comment: What's your targetf? How is it defined? Given the method, the log looks suspicious.

Comment: Apparently the problem was that targetf delivered infinite return values at 2,2,0,0; ruling this out solves the problem. It's strange that `find_min` is able to deal with that, whereas the constrained optimization apparenlty is not. I see that I should make sure that this doesn't happen, but given the output I would still expect a different return value (or an error message instead).